# compile error about template deduction on c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>                                                                         
class X {
public:
  using I = int;                                                                         
  void f(I i) {
    std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl;
  }
};

template <int N>
void fppm(void (X<N>::*p)(typename X<N>::I)) {
  p(0);
}

int main() {
  fppm(&X<33>::f); 
  return 0;
}
```

I just don't understand the compile error message of the code.

```
error: called object type 'void (X<33>::*)(typename X<33>::I)' is not a function or function pointer
 p(0);
```

I think p is a function which returns void and takes `int` as its argument. But apparently, it's not. Could somebody give me clue?

Comment: It's a non-static member function. You need an instance of `X<33>` to call it _on_ (or just make it static).

Comment: It's the call that is the problem, `p(0);` is not the way to call a member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `p` is a pointer to a nonstatic member function, you need an instance to call it with. Thus, first instantiate an object of `X<33>` in main:

```
int main() {
  X<33> x;
  fppm(x, &X<33>::f); // <-- Signature changed below to accept an instance
```

Then in your function, change the code to accept an instance of `X<N>` and call the member function for it:

```
template <int N>
void fppm(X<N> instance, void (X<N>::*p)(typename X<N>::I)) {
  (instance.*p)(0);
}
```

The syntax may look ugly but the low precedence of the pointer to member operator requires the need for the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

As denoted in the comments already, `p` is a pointer to member function, but you call it like a static function (`p(0);`). You need a concrete object to call `p` on:

```
X<N> x;
(x.*p)(0);
// or:
X<N>* xx = new X<N>();
(xx->*p)(0);
delete xx;
```

Be aware that the `.*`/`->*` operators have lower precedence than the function call operator, thus you *need* the parentheses.

Side note: Above is for better illustration, modern C++ might use `auto` keyword and smart pointers instead, which could look like this:

```
auto x = std::make_unique<X<N>>();
(x.get()->*p)(0);
```